# Implementing State Machine for e-Commerce (Django)

Tags: python, django, session, e-commerce, state-machine

I'm thinking of implementing a State Machine for an eCommerce project - specifically for the workflow from an empty cart to the state where payment is made.

In addition, the Cart is stored in session using Django's session framework. I can't wrap my head around whether the state machine should be part of the Cart implementation or standalone, but is 'connected' to the Cart via API.

Just a disclaimer, I'm really new to State Machines so I'm not too familiar with the theoretical concepts but from my own research it seems like something really useful for my project.

My thought process is as such:

`state_machine.py`

```
class StateMachine(object):
    states = ['empty', 'filled', 'prepayment', 'payment_auth', 'order_placed']

    ... # methods that trigger state changes
```

and in the `cart.py`, each action might trigger a change in state:

```
state_machine = StateMachine()

class Cart(object):
    ...
    def add_item(self):
        ...
        # add item to cart
        # then trigger state change
        state_machine.fill_cart() --> triggers a state change from 'empty' to 'filled'
```

The session should store something like this:

```
request.session[some_session_key] = {
    'state': 'filled',
    'cart': {
        # cart stuff goes here
    },
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is redundant, that perhaps I should implement the State within the Cart itself (as an attribute) and not as a separate object.

Would appreciate any advice!

Comment: [django-fsm](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-fsm) may be what you need

Comment: @Nghung I took a look at it. It seems like it's meant for models, if I'm storing the states and cart information in session, I won't be using models..is fsm still relevant? Maybe I missed out something

Comment: sorry I missed out that you are using session. Please take a look at the [transitions](https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions) package. A [callback](https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions#callbacks) to change session status can be attached when an object leaves or enters a state.

Comment: @Nghung great, thanks! This looks like something I could use for sure. Thank you :) do you want to post an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, a state machine implementation in Python named [transitions](https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions) suits the need of the OP. Callbacks can be attached when an object enters or leaves a specific state, which can be used to set session state.

```
# Our old Matter class, now with  a couple of new methods we
# can trigger when entering or exit states.
class Matter(object):
    def say_hello(self): 
        print("hello, new state!")
    def say_goodbye(self): 
        print("goodbye, old state!")

lump = Matter()
states = [
    State(name='solid', on_exit=['say_goodbye']),
    'liquid',
    { 'name': 'gas' }
    ]
machine = Machine(lump, states=states)
machine.add_transition('sublimate', 'solid', 'gas')

# Callbacks can also be added after initialization using
# the dynamically added on_enter_ and on_exit_ methods.
# Note that the initial call to add the callback is made
# on the Machine and not on the model.
machine.on_enter_gas('say_hello')

# Test out the callbacks...
machine.set_state('solid')
lump.sublimate()
>>> 'goodbye, old state!'
>>> 'hello, new state!'
```